# Efficiency of Insert into on duplicate key update with many if expresssion

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize the efficiency of one sql
it looks like:

```
Insert into order_table ( id, business_line, order_type,...)
values(1123123,4,5,·····)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 business_line = IF( _version <= 6 ,10,business_line),
 order_type = IF( _version <= 6 ,2,order_type)
..........
```

With many if condition

And it runs slow.(about 250ms)

Is there any way to bind so many 'if' together? Such as:

```
Insert into order_table ( id, business_line, order_type,...)
values(1123123,4,5,·····)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 SET (business_line,order_type,...) = 
IF( _version <= 6 ,(10,2),(business_line,order_type)),
..........
```

Any suggest will be appreciated

Comment: Are you inserting 1 row?  Or a million rows from `SELECT ...`?  Where does `_version` come from?

Comment: I'm inserting 1 row with many field,  '_version' is just one of them .  '_version' mean the times of this record has been changed

Comment: Is there a `VALUES` clause in the IODKU?

Comment: yes I'll change my question

Answer (score 0):

When the goal is to "UPDATE" several specific rows.  Use a unique key (such as `id`):

```
INSERT INTO t
    (id, a,b,c)
  VALUES
    (654, 1,2,3),
    (666, 11,22,33),
    ...
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    b = VALUES(b),
    c = VALUES(c);
```

When the goal is to "INSERT" several new rows.  Don't supply any unique value (such as an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id`):

```
INSERT INTO t
    (id, a,b,c)
  VALUES
    (NULL, 1,2,3),
    (NULL, 11,22,33),
    ...
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    b = VALUES(b);
```

Equivalently, leave out the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and the `NULLs`.

Note:  Version 8.0 wants this syntax instead:

```
    b = NEW.b
```

(Caveat:  Test this in your environment; I have not experimented with all variations.)

This technique should be faster because:

- Only one roundtrip to the server
- If `autocommit=ON`, then only one transaction for the batch.